# Windows 10 mobile orrientation still there?

Tags: c#, orientation, windows-mobile

I am porting an app from windows phone 7.x silverlight to windows 10 mobile.
I used to be able to check the orientation and set the orientation of the application in the following way:

```
if (DeviceStatus.IsKeyboardDeployed)
{
    if (Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
    {
        SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
        Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
        {
            SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
            Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        });
    }
}
```

When I want to do this in UWP it is not possible and the only way to set the orientation to something is to do the following:

```
var k = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

Of course this does nothing because I need to assign k to the orientation but there is nothing to do this..

Is this still possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn934798.aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.autorotationpreferences.aspx

So i my case this will be :

```
using Windows.Graphics.Display;

DisplayOrientations = Orientation.Horizontal;
```